# Tensorflow vs Numpy concat operation

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, tensorflow, tensor

I was just trying some code in numpy and tensorflow , since tensorflow uses numpy in the back-end i was not expecting differences in certain operations like `concat` operation.

> In Numpy

```
z = np.array(
[
 [
   [1,2,3,],
   [4,5,6,]
 ],

 [
   [7,8,9],
   [10,11,12]
 ],

 [
   [13,14,15],
   [16,17,18]
 ]

])
```

np.concatenate(z ,axis=1) gives

```
array([[ 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 13, 14, 15],
[ 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 16, 17, 18]])
```

> In Tensorflow

```
hello = tf.constant(value = [
        [
            [1,2,3,],
            [4,5,6,]
        ],

        [
            [7,8,9],
            [10,11,12]
        ],

        [
            [13,14,15],
            [16,17,18]
        ]

    ] )

tf.concat(hello ,axis=1) gives

array([[[ 1, 2, 3],
[ 4, 5, 6]],

   [[ 7,  8,  9],
    [10, 11, 12]],

   [[13, 14, 15],
    [16, 17, 18]]])
```

why is this difference

Comment: `np.concatenate` expects a list of arrays, or an equivalent.  In this case it treats `z` as a list of 3 2d arrays.  `np.concatenate( list(z), axis=1))` does the same thing.

Comment: @hpaulj Exactely.

Answer (score 3):

[`tf.concat`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat) expects a *list* of tensors to be concatenated along an axis. If you specify only one tensor, it will just print that tensor and does nothing.